# eConnect timesheet entry multicurrency issue

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect

I'm trying to use econnect to insert TimeSheet Entry batches from an external system via "taPATimeSheetLineInsert".

When using the fuctionnal currency everything works fine.

The problem is that when I use another currency, the ACCRUED REVENUES are set to 0.

I tried to enter the same entry manually in GP and the accrued revenues are OK. When you take a look at it in the UI everything is the same in both timesheet entryes.

(I specifed the currency id which is different from the functionnal currency and I provide a PAUNITCOST as requested by eConnect.)

If I look into the PA10001 TABLE, there are differences between the record inserted manually and the one inserted with eConnect as the value of "PA_Base_Billing_Rate" and "PAORIGBSBILLRTE" are set to 0. The ACCRUED REVENUE COLUMN is evidently different as well.

There is no option in taPATimeSheetLineInsert that can help me so I don't know what to do to make it work!

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know we resolved the problem "temporarily" and I would hate to find an unanswered post about that problem if I were to be someone else having the same problem.

The problem with the econnect storedproc (taPATimeSheetLineInsert ) is that it does thing differently than the timesheet entry inside GP.

Looks like it tries to use the forecast profit amount instead of the profit amount set in the Project Budget.

Funny that there is no usable data in the Forecast and that the stored procedure tries to get it anyway.

For now, we added a bit of code to get the paprofitamt instead of  paforecastbaseprofitamt.

Still have no clue about why the code was made like that but everything works fine.

Have fun people!